# How can I resize the icon?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, icons, size

I changed icon of `JFrame`. But that is very small.
So I'd like to change its size. Please help

```
import java.awt.*;

//@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameD extends JFrame{

    public FrameD(){


        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\hilalekinci\\fiha.png");

        this.setTitle("FiHa");
        this.setSize(750,550);
        this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(300,80);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new FrameD();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't "change" the size of the image used by the window or taskbar, but you can supply a series of images to allow the API to make decisions about which icon it might use based on the current settings of the OS

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't. The icon size of a window is controlled by the window mananger which runs the application. Some windows managers don't even show an icon.

You can provide alternative icons with different sizes (see method `setIconImages()`), but the windows manager will decide which icon will be displayed. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29):

> `public void setIconImages(List<? extends Image> icons)`
>
> Sets the sequence of images to be displayed as the icon for this window. Subsequent calls to getIconImages will always return a copy of the icons list.
>
> Depending on the platform capabilities one or several images of different dimensions will be used as the window's icon.
>
> The icons list is scanned for the images of most appropriate dimensions from the beginning. If the list contains several images of the same size, the first will be used.
>
> Ownerless windows with no icon specified use platfrom-default icon. The icon of an owned window may be inherited from the owner unless explicitly overridden. Setting the icon to null or empty list restores the default behavior.
>
> Note : Native windowing systems may use different images of differing dimensions to represent a window, depending on the context (e.g. window decoration, window list, taskbar, etc.). They could also use just a single image for all contexts or no image at all.